# How to setup Airflow > 2.0 high availability cluster on centos 7 or above

Tags: airflow, cluster-computing, high-availability

I want to setup HA for airflow(2.3.1) on centos7. Messaging queue - Rabbitmq and metadata db - postgres. Anybody knows how to setup it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very large, because the high availability has multiple level and definition:

- Airflow availability: multiple scheduler, multiple workers, auto scaling to avoid pressure, high storage volume, ...
- The databases: a HA cluster for `Rabbitmq` and a HA cluster for `postgres`
- Even if you have the first two levels, how many node you want to use? you cannot put everything in the same node, you need to run one service replica per node
- Suppose you did that, and now you have 3 different nodes running in the same data center, what if there is a fire in the data center? So you need to use multiple nodes in different regions
- After doing all of above, is there a risk for network problem? of course there is

If you just want to run airflow in HA mode, you have multiple option to do that on any OS:

- docker compose: usually we use it for developing, but you can use it for production too, you can create multiple scheduler instances, with multiple workers, it can help you to improve the availability of your service
- docker swarm: similar to docker compose with additional features (scaling, multi nodes, ...), you will not find much resources to install it, but you can use the compose files and just do some changes
- kubernetes: the best solution, K8S can help you to ensure the availability of your services, easy install with helm
- or just running the different services on your host: not recommended, because of manual tasks, and applying the HA is complicated